# Spring Rest Template that returns a List of a base type

Tags: java, spring, generics

Is it possible to get the Spring Rest Template, in conjunction with a ParameterizedTypeReference, to return a List of  base type.  I want to specify the actual type to the ParameterizedTypeReference.  I have tried but only got to the point where I get a List of HashMaps.

```
List<BaseObject> response = null;
re = restTemplate.exchange(requestUrl, HttpMethod.GET, getHttpStringEntity(), 
                    getParametrizedTypeReference(Class.forName("my.package." + this.entity)) );

private HttpEntity<String> getHttpStringEntity()
    {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

        return entity;
    }

    private <T> ParameterizedTypeReference<List<T>> getParametrizedTypeReference(Type T)
    {
        return new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<T>>() {};
    }
```